# Abstract class accessing its child class functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Is it possible to access the child's function members from a pointer of an abstract class as the parent?
This is the abstract class

```
class Item {
    public:
        virtual double getTotalPrice() = 0;
};
```

This is the child class

```
class Product : public Item {
    protected:
        string name;
    public:
        Product() {}
        string getName() {}
        double getTotalPrice() {}
};
```

Is it possible in the main driver to access this getName() function from an instance of the Item class, as I want to display the total price and the name of the product also?

Comment: @churill Because this is just a rough sketch of the hierarchy and the name has to be to as a parameter to this Product class as there are other parameters that Product has.

Comment: If you cannot do something on all kinds of `Item` then you need to rethink your design of attempting to do it on some of them. Please consider whether we might be looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem It is much better to continue detailing the design than to start working around problems caused by design gaps.

Comment: @Yunnosch I totally agree with you about redesigning. But unfortunately, i can't in this example. So the original code was only the Product class which had these parameters like name, description, etc, now I needed to add an abstract class that would be the parent, and I am not allowed to change the original code.

Comment: Well, the class you aren't allowed to change has UB since the member functions that are supposed to return something, does not.

Comment: But the change would only be needed inside `Item` (which you can change), not inside `Product` (which you cannot). Whatever the details (including those you already commented) please add them to the quesiotion, by [edit]ing. They are helpful.

Comment: You are right it is allowed to declare whatever function in the Item so i just declared the getName as virtual and it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- You need your base class to have a `virtual` destructor if you should be able to `delete` objects through a base class pointer.
- Make `getName` `virtual` too.

```
class Item {
public:
    virtual ~Item() = default;
    virtual const string& getName() /* const */ = 0;
    virtual double getTotalPrice() /* const */ = 0;
};
```

---

Note that the `Product` class that you aren't allowed to change is slightly flawed.

- It doesn't return values where it should.
- The getter member functions are not `const`.

Suggest some changes if you can't do it yourself:

```
class Product : public Item {
private: // prefer private member variables
    string name;
public:
    Product() = default;
    const string& getName() const override { return name; }
    double getTotalPrice() const override {
       // why is this implemented here when there's no price to return?
       return {};
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes i should have just done that in the first place but i was not sure if it was allowed. Thank you!

Comment: I understand the changes you have suggested and they are very good, but this was just a sketch of the hierarchy, in the real program the functions have their own body and are constants getters, I am sorry to have you confused i just needed the concept if it was possible or not. But thank you sincerely!

Comment: @HermesÇati Ok, then I understand :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an instance of the **abstract** `Item` class (because it's abstract) but you can have an `Item` pointer (or reference) to a derived (and non-abstract) `Product` class.

But because `Item` declares no `getName()` , you'd probably need to do a `dynamic_cast` to check if the pointee is really a `Product`, for ex.

```
Item* item = new Product();
...

// at same later time or some ooter function:
// use dynamic_cast to check if the pointee is the type you expect it to be

Product* p = dynamic_cast<Product>(item);
if (p) p->getName();
```

Though, not directly targeting your question I think there is also a design issue here. Something like Product conists of many items so it's rather 1:N composition relationship. For getting total price a concept (for ex. Billable ) would be mnore appropriate.
So I would probably advise something like following for the class hierarhy:

```
class Billable
{
public:
    virtual double getTotalPrice() const = 0;
    virtual ~Billable() {}
};

class Item : public Billable
{
    string name;
public:
    string getName() const { return name; }
    double getTotalPrice() const override { ... impl .. }
    // ... rest 
}

class Product : public Billable
{
    string name;
    vector<Items> items;
public:
    string getName() const { return name; }
    double getTotalPrice() const override
    {
         return accumulate(begin(items), end(items), 0, [](auto i) { return i->getTotalPrice(); });
    }
    // ... rest ...
    
}
```

Comment: Yeah definitely this hierarchy structure is much better but I guess sometimes you just have to obey the professors wishes.

Comment: understand. was just a thought

Answer (score 0):

You can static cast if you're sure that the pointer points to an actual object of type `Product` or dynamic cast if you're not sure and want to check it first. This doesn't work if the pointer doesn't point to an object of the derived class.

```
class Item {
    public:
        virtual double getTotalPrice() = 0;
};

class Product : public Item {
    protected:
        string name;
    public:
        Product() {}
        string getName() {return {};}
        double getTotalPrice() {return {};}
};

int main() {
    Product p;
    Item *i = &p;
    
    static_cast<Product *>(i)->getName();

    auto *ptr = dynamic_cast<Product *>(i);
    if (ptr) ptr->getName();
}
```

`dynamic_cast` requires runtime type information (RTTP) and comes with some extra costs.

Usually it's better to redesign the architecture instead of downcast.

Comment: I used the dynamic cast, to be honest, but the problem with the dynamic cast is that you have to do this every time a new instance of Item is created.

Comment: @MericOzcan It works for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9hKiA4M7Q4PoNUR1

Comment: @MericOzcan The question and all other answers are without includes and namespaces but you insist to add it to this answer. Why?